# Using Orchard login in external site

Tags: c#, .net, orchardcms

I'm developing a web application in C# called "ProjectX" and a Orchard Site (1.6).
I want to use Orchard users and roles in "ProjectX". The idea is centralize the login manager in one site only (Orchard).

Basically the user do the logon on Orchard Site and he'll redirect for "ProjectX", after that I need use the roles for some process, e.g:

```
if (role == "customer") 
 call method1();
else
 call method2();
```

We want the fairly easy solution to do that and I notice that Orchard creates two Cookies after SignIn process but I don't know if it can help me on validation.

Is it possible to do?
Could anyone help me with ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks more practical to use a *real* single sign on system, something that has been designed for that purpose, and have both Orchard and that other application use that.

Comment: Thank you Bertrand.
Do you have some example or how can I find it?

Comment: I got your suggestion.
But I want to try some solutions before that.
If I add a reference to Orchard.Framework.dll can I access the authentication methods, like GetAuthenticatedUser()?